# Is there a way to rewrite the onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the code i have below is not rendering, in the onClick event the first condition is highlighting there is an error but the btn is defined already.

```
<ButtonContainer>
        {
          btnValues.map((btn, i) => {
            return (
              <Button
                key={i}
                value={btn}
                className={btn === '=' ? 'equals' : ''}
                onClick{
                  btn === 'C'
                  ? resetClickHandler
                  : btn === "+-"
                  ? invertClickHandler
                  : btn === "%"
                  ? percentClickHandler
                  : btn === "="
                  ? equalsClickHandler
                  : btn === "/" || btn === "X" || btn === "-" || btn === "+"
                  ? signClickHandler
                  : btn === "."
                  ? commaClickHandler
                  : numClickHandler
                }/>
            );
          })
        }
      </ButtonContainer>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). At a minimum, copy and paste the error into the question. But it would be better to show us the definitions of `btnValues` and the various functions (if they're functions).

Comment: **It's just a typo**, there's no `=` after `onClick` before `{`.

Answer (score -1):

i assume you missed **=** here and also try to render it using () like this:

```
btnValues.map((btn, i) => (
              <Button
                key={i}
                value={btn}
                className={btn === '=' ? 'equals' : ''}
                onClick = {
                  btn === 'C'
                  ? resetClickHandler
                  : btn === "+-"
                  ? invertClickHandler
                  : btn === "%"
                  ? percentClickHandler
                  : btn === "="
                  ? equalsClickHandler
                  : btn === "/" || btn === "X" || btn === "-" || btn === "+"
                  ? signClickHandler
                  : btn === "."
                  ? commaClickHandler
                  : numClickHandler
                }/>
            ))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's great to want to help! But we don't post *answers* to typo questions here. Instead, we post comments and close the question. Once your rep is >= 50, you'll be able to post comments.

Comment: There's no need to change the `map` callback from a full function body to a concise function body, it makes no difference.